# Как обновить Ubuntu до 19.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Пытаюсь обновить Ubuntu с 19.04 до 19.10. Использую команду `sudo update-manager -d`. Открывается окно, в котором сообщается, что да, есть новая версия. Нажимаю "обновить", в терминале сначала появляется сообщение

> Проверка наличия нового релиза Ubuntu.

Затем сообщение

> Перед обновлением установите все доступные обновления для своей версии.

`sudo apt update` и `sudo apt upgrade` ничего нового не устанавливают.

Comment: dist-upgrade. .

Comment: @andreymal Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

---

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Откройте и отредактируйте файл / etc / update-manager / release-upgrade и убедитесь, что переменная Prompt установлена в normal

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=normal
```

---

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

**Restart-OS**

Comment: Не работает :( И еще я земетил при попытке установить vim вот такую ошибку `vim : Зависит: libpython3.7 (>= 3.7.0) но он не будет установлен`

Comment: sudo apt install -f

Comment: Получаю сообщение о том, что 5 пакетов не обновлены. Во время выполнения команды update получаю список этих пакетов. Следующие пакеты будут оставлены в неизменном виде:
  gdb libpeas-1.0-0 libsmbclient libwbclient0 samba-libs

Comment: or
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade

Comment: Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 5 пакетов не обновлено.

Comment: $ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100122/discussion-between-aa-arsenenko-and--).

Answer (score 3):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. apt upgrade не помогал, т.е. ничего не обновлял. Вывел список не обновленных пакетов командой :

```
> apt list --upgradable
Вывод списка… Готово
apache2-bin/disco-updates,disco-security 2.4.38-2ubuntu2.3 amd64 [может быть обновлён с: 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.6]
plasma-vault/disco 5.15.4-0ubuntu1 amd64 [может быть обновлён с: 5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1]
url-dispatcher/disco 0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu4 amd64 [может быть обновлён с: 0.1+16.04.20151110-0ubuntu2]
```

Попробовал  обновить вручную и выяснилось что сломана зависимость с libcurl4 из-за пакета msodbcsql:

```
> sudo apt install apache2-bin 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 apache2-bin : Зависит: libcurl4 (>= 7.16.2) но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.

>sudo apt install libcurl4
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 msodbcsql : Зависит: libcurl3 но он не будет установлен
E: Ошибка: pkgProblemResolver::Resolve привёл к появлению сломанных пакетов. Это может быть вызвано зафиксированными пакетами.
```

После удаления пакета:

```
>sudo apt remove msodbcsql
```

Все обновления установились и обновление релиза пошло успешно.